# Accessing bazel files outside the docker

Tags: c++, docker, bazel

I am quite new to docker environment and need help in understanding / fixing the below issue.

Scenario:
I am running an application (assume App1) inside the docker.
This application/docker uses bazel framework. So the run time files (some C++ .h and .cc files) which are getting generated are saved inside directory Bazel-App1.

I can use those generated files in some other code inside the docker. However I am not able to link those files (which are inside the bazel-App1 directory) to the codes which I am writing outside the docker.

Is there a way I can get access to those files?

Kindly let me know if you need more details to suggest me a fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying files from Docker container to host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049212/copying-files-from-docker-container-to-host)

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the response. The question is more or less similar. However in my case I am using bazel framework inside the docker. Looks like the files generated inside the bazel are not accessible outside. Could you please clarify.

Comment: Same problem as [accessing container files from IDE running Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50010108/can-my-local-eclipse-install-access-libraries-in-docker-container/50010312#50010312). You'll need to use docker volumes pointing to the directory containing generated code.